# How to get screen orientation (including upside down options) now that getDefaultDisplay() is deprecated?

Tags: android, orientation

I've been using this code for many years and it works perfectly:

```
final int orientation = myActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() * 90;
```

The `* 90` part happens to yield rotation in degrees, which is convenient but not essential. The main point is that it returns 0, 1, 2 or 3 and lets you distinguish "normal" portrait / landscape from their upside down variants.

The current suggestion is `getConfiguration().orientation`, but there is only `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` and `ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`, which is not suitable for my needs - I need to detect the upside down positions as well. How to do this without using `getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Context#getDisplay`<sup>[[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager#getDefaultDisplay())]</sup>, retrieve the nullable `Display` object and then simply use `Display#getRotation` to get the roation.

E.g.
`orientation = myActivity.getDisplay().getRotation()*90` (don't forget the null checks)

I hope this helps, out of curiosity, what is your use case where you need to destingush between these 4 cases?

Comment: Thanks! That call is API level 30 minimum, so I guess I need an `if` to choose between my original code and your code at runtime.

Comment: Yes, since this is something, that someone has to do often, I personally always use a seperate class to mask those API differences. E.g. `DisplayCompat#getRotation.`